# displacement map overlap at sharp edges

Tags: modeling, modifiers, texture-baking

My displacement map seems of overlap and project upside down at sharp edges, I am modelling a creature and the teeth are heavily distorted.

Any idea how to solve this?

[image]
Here is the error of the displacement map of the low poly mesh

[image]

Low poly mesh

[image]

high poly

It happens at the finger tips as well, turning down strength doesn't solve it, and all normals are in the right position.

Comment: Try adjusting the strength to a lower value so that it doesn't intersect.

Comment: I have and it doesn't disappear until its at 0, thanks anyway tho, any other ideas what might be causing it?

Comment: Then try tweaking the midlevel. I think I higher value should work better.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the responses, much appreciated, I think i figured it out tho, my problem was that my mesh was way to small, I sized it up and it seems to work fine, thanks again